# ImageView below adview stop layout jump after ad loads

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have an imageview that I will place different images.

This images can have many sizes like 200x200 200x400 400x200...

Above `imageview` I have an adview and below this imageview I need 4 buttons.

The problem is, I'd like the image be below adview, but stop jumping position when ad loads. It goes down when an ad loads, I'd to stop this move, make the image fix, but above the adview.

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
        android:contentDescription="img"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ad_view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a1"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.207"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.447" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a2"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.806"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.447" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a3"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.207"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.582" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a4"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.806"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.582" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

The fastest solution would be to change your ad view  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`  into `android:layout_height="fixed size"` so your ad view will have a single height and won't change because of its `wrap_content` attribute (If your ad view is not loaded you can think of `wrap_content` as height of 0 and only after its loaded it will have height, thus the layout jump).

**Why is it bad?**

your layout won't be responsive.

**How to fix?**

Read the answer below.

---

### Long but better answer:

You can use [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) with   `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".2"` to tell your guideline to be at the top of your screen (80%) and constraint your ad view to your guideline - this way your layout will won't jump (it will have its space to load into).

Another thing, different phones got **different screen size**, in your layout you are using fixed size on your view (fixed size is 50dp for example) and the result is that what may look good on one screen (your android studio preview screen) will not look good on another screen (your actual phone).

Here is an example to achieve your wanted look using `ConstaintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout   
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.08"
    android:text="add view"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="a1"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.08"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/a3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/a2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="a2"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.08"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/a1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/a1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="a3"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.08"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/a1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/a1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a1" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="a4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/a3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/a2"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.08"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/a2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a3" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is how it will look (I am adding a screenshot from the layout editor for better understanding ConstaintLayout)

[image]

---

### Some extra information:

ConstraintLayout is not meant to have  nested view groups (in your case you have `LinearLayout` inside `constraintlayout`).

> ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.

You can Use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) with [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) and [Chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) to support different screen sizes, you won't have to use fixed sizes on your views and you will be able to use a single layout to support different screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Give the adview or it's surrounding layout a minimum height equal to the smart banner content in your case likely 90px.

It's jumping because with no content loaded your `wrap_content` height = 0, then it gets a new height of *x*, so your imageview shifts down *x*.